# Json formado erróneamente en petición get desde Codeigniter a AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, json, http, codeigniter-3

resulta que tengo un problema recibiendo un json desde codeigniter a AngularJS.

En el controlador de codeigniter tengo el siguiente código.

```
public function dptos() {
    $data = array("res" => "empty", 'data' => array('mango', 'banana', 'pera'));
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Tengo un servicio en AngularJS (Angular 1) que llama a la anterior función así:

```
sigc.factory('DptoMpioService', ['$http', function($http){
return {
    dptos: function()
    {
        return $http({
            url: 'index.php/Dptompio/dptos/',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        });
    }
}}]);
```

Y por ultimo desde un controlador en AngularJS llamo al servicio

```
DptoMpioService.dptos().success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.res);
    }).error(function(error){
        console.log(error)
    });
```

Pero el problema es que estoy obteniendo el json mal formado, el ***console.log(data)*** obtiene:

```
:{"res":"empty","data":["mango","banana","pera"]}
```

y el ***console.log(data.res)*** obtiene ***Undefined***

El problema son los dos puntos al principio del json, pero no tengo idea de porque pone estos dos puntos, ya que siempre había utilizado este método y nunca me había dado problema, alguna idea de que este pasando.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Los métodos `success` y `error` son obsoletos. Deberías usar `then` y `catch`. Si reemplazas `success` por `then` que valor tiene `response.data`?: `.then(function(response) { console.log(response.data); })`

Comment: Gracias por lo del success no sabia que estaba obsoleto, el problema acabo de solucionarlo, era algo que había digitado mal en un archivo de un modelo en codeigniter lo que generaba el error.